# Why evolution 3.18 creates multiple copies in the send folder?

Tags: 16.04, evolution, mail

When sending a mail with evolution 3.18.5.2 the window of the composed mail stays open on the following status "Storing send message to 'INBOX/Sent' (100% complete)"

When quitting this, the sent mail was recieved normally but multiple copies of this mail were stored in the sent folder of the mail account. The longer you wait for quitting this, the more copies will be stored.

This problem does not occur with a second mail account and also not with thunderbird or geary.
I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and evolution worked fine in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: The problem of multiple copies always occurs in evolution, when moving a mail to one of the folders of the mail account, even to the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it could be solved by using the correct port of the SMTP server. Go to the settings of your selected account, go to the page, where the SMTP server is specified, change the port to the number your provider uses (e.g. 465 instead of 587 which in my case was automatically assigned by Evolution) and select the correct method of authentification (e.g. STARTTLS). Furthermore you can try to change the folder where Evolution saves your messages on the next page of the account settings. Often it is called "Sent Item", but Evolution tries to use a folder "Sent".

If none of the above works you could try to tell Evolution to save sent messages in a local folder on your computer by enabling the local account and setting it as the saving destination.

I hope that this helps.